# Additional interfaces in Routing and Remote Access

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, routing, windows-server-2012, rras

Ok, so some of my basic installs use Routing and Remote Access the only problem is if I need to add additional Interfaces they only way I can seem to be able to do it is to disable and delete the service and then recreate it from scratch. Which luckily so far most of the system have been quite a simple setup so its not taken too long.

I seem to be having issue in both Windows Server 2008 R2 and 2012, I can't comment on the others I have not tired it.

The problem is with trying to add an interface from a physical NIC or virtual adaptor. There is no options to add one, the only interface you can add is a demand-dial interface. Restarting the system or service does nothing.

Does anyone know of any fixes for this? or quick solutions that don't including rebuilding the routing server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I have found to a solution is the below.

- Open RegEdit.exe. Go to
  "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces"
  where each of your network adaptors (physical or virtual) has a GUID
  named sub-key.
- Identify which one is your network adapter (look at
  the IP or DHCP settings in the child key=values or configure a
  temporary address so you can find it). Copy or note down the 
  GUID. (Click the GUID key then hit F2 to goto rename mode and
  highlight the whole key, hit CTRL+C to copy to the clipboard.)
- Go to
  "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\RemoteAccess\Interfaces". Add
  a new sub-key which is the next in sequence, for example I had
  1...6 so I added "7". In is key add the following...

  - A DWORD32 (32bit integer) called "Enabled" set to 1.
  - A REG_SZ (string) called "InterfaceName" then paste your interface GUID, e.g. set to "{XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}".
  - A DWORD32 called "Stamp" set to 0.
  - A DWORD32 called "Type" set to 3 (LAN).
- Restart RRAS, the interface will appear! Right click each protocol, e.g. IPv4, IPv6 then you can right click "General" to add a "New Interface..." and your interface will then be enabled for that protocol.